# Calculating exponents in C without pow()

Tags: c

```
int main ()
{
    int n = 0;
    int base = 0;
    while(n < 10)
    {
        int x = 2;
        int answer = power(x, n);
        float neganswer = negpower(x, n);
        printf("%d %d %f\n", base, answer, neganswer);
        base++;
        n++;
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

int power(int base, int power)
{
    int result, i;
    result = 1;
    for (i=0; i < power; i++)
    {
        result *= base;
    }
    return result;
}

int negpower(int base, int power)
{
    float result, i;

    result = 1.0;

    for (i=0; i < power; i++)
    {
        result = result / base;
    }
    return result;
}
```

So I'm trying to call upon this function that i've made, and I think its calculating it correctly, however it is only outputting 1.0000000 followed directly by 0.0000000. I think I've got problems with carrying the float value, can anyone chime in?

Thanks

Comment: It's not wise to make your loop index a float (though it shouldn't cause trouble in this case).

Comment: What I'd do (in addition to fixing the return type from negpower) is have negpower return `1.0 / power(base, power)`.  (And I'd also change the variable "power" to something else -- it's a very bad idea to use the same name for multiple items.)

Comment: Took your advice Hot Licks, I don't know how I didn't use the reciprocal before hand. However I can't select your answer as best answer since its a comment, correct?

Comment: That's alright.  I hate getting pinned down to a precise answer.

Comment: I also have another question, my first output is 1.0000000, followed by 0.500000, then 0.2500000, and then the ammount of numbers after the decimal grows. Is there a way to remove all the useless 0s after 0.500000, albeit without removing the useful decimals for the last output, which is 0.0.001953.

Comment: Now you can "optimize" the power function a bit.  Observe that if you divide base in half (and hang on to any remainder) you can repeatedly multiply times base squared for base/2 iterations.  And you can further divide by 2 and make it even faster.  (Works out well for a recursive algorithm, BTW.)

Comment: What you're seeing there is floating point being floating point.  No general solution other than to (somehow) not use floating point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are returning a `float` from `negpower()` which has return type of `int` and assigning it to a `float neganswer`.
Change

```
int negpower(int base, int power)
```

to

```
float negpower(int base, int power)
```

Output:

[image]

Side note:

> - Always add required header files.
> - A prototype should be declared if a function definition appears after the `main()`.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is much simpler. Your negpower function returns an `int`, when you actually return a `float` from it. Change the prototype and it should work alright.

Comment: Well, that second point is probably not true, since `result` is of type `float` in that function.

Comment: @DennisMeng Apologies, I misread that. I sometimes forget the type promotion rules of C, so I've removed that bit. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is optimized library if you are interested:

```
#ifdef  DOCUMENTATION
title   pow x raised to power y
index   x raised to power y
usage
    .s
    double x, y, f, pow();
    .br
    f = pow(x, y);
    .s
description
    .s
    Returns value of x raised to power y
    .s
diagnostics
    .s
    There are three error possible error messages from this function.
    .s
    If the x argument is negative the message 'pow arg negative',
    followed by the value of x, is written to stderr.  The value 
    of pow for |x| is returned.
    .s
    If x = 0.0 and y <= 0.0 or if result overflows the message 'pow
    overflow', followed by the value of y, is written to stderr.
    The value of HUGE is returned.
    .s
    If the result underflows and if warnings are enabled (normally not),
    the message 'pow underflow', followed by the value of y, is written
    to stderr.  The value of 0 is returned.
    .s
    The suggestion of Cody and Waite, that the domain be reduced to
    simplify the overflow test, has been adopted, consequently overflow
    is reported if the result would exceed HUGE * 2**(-1/16). 
    2**(-1/16) is approximately 0.9576.
    .s
internal
    .s
    Algorithm from Cody and Waite pp. 84-124.  This algorithm required
    two auxiliary programs POWGA1 and POWGA2 to calculate, respectively,
    the arrays a1[] and a2[] used to represent the powers of 2**(-1/16)
    to more than machine precision.
    The source code for these programs are in the files POWGA1.AUX and
    POWGA2.AUX.  The octal table on page 98 of Cody and Waite is in the
    file POWOCT.DAT which is required on stdin by POWGA2.
    .s
author
    .s
    Hamish Ross.
    .s
date
    .s
    27-Jan-85
#endif

#include <math.h>

#define MAXEXP 2031     /* (MAX_EXP * 16) - 1           */
#define MINEXP -2047        /* (MIN_EXP * 16) - 1           */

static double a1[] = {
    1.0,
    0.95760328069857365,
    0.91700404320467123,
    0.87812608018664974,
    0.84089641525371454,
    0.80524516597462716,
    0.77110541270397041,
    0.73841307296974966,
    0.70710678118654752,
    0.67712777346844637,
    0.64841977732550483,
    0.62092890603674203,
    0.59460355750136054,
    0.56939431737834583,
    0.54525386633262883,
    0.52213689121370692,
    0.50000000000000000
};
static double a2[] = {
     0.24114209503420288E-17,
     0.92291566937243079E-18,
    -0.15241915231122319E-17,
    -0.35421849765286817E-17,
    -0.31286215245415074E-17,
    -0.44654376565694490E-17,
     0.29306999570789681E-17,
     0.11260851040933474E-17
};
static double p1 = 0.833333333333332114e-1;
static double p2 = 0.125000000005037992e-1;
static double p3 = 0.223214212859242590e-2;
static double p4 = 0.434457756721631196e-3;
static double q1 = 0.693147180559945296e0;
static double q2 = 0.240226506959095371e0;
static double q3 = 0.555041086640855953e-1;
static double q4 = 0.961812905951724170e-2;
static double q5 = 0.133335413135857847e-2;
static double q6 = 0.154002904409897646e-3;
static double q7 = 0.149288526805956082e-4;
static double k = 0.442695040888963407;
double pow(x, y)
double x, y;
{
    double frexp(), g, ldexp(), r, u1, u2, v, w, w1, w2, y1, y2, z;
    int iw1, m, p;

    if (y == 0.0)
    return(1.0);
    if (x <= 0.0) {
    if (x == 0.0) {
        if (y > 0.0)
        return(x);
        cmemsg(FP_POWO, &y);
        return(HUGE);
    }
    else {
        cmemsg(FP_POWN, &x);
        x = -x;
    }
    }
    g = frexp(x, &m);
    p = 0;
    if (g <= a1[8])
    p = 8;
    if (g <= a1[p + 4])
    p += 4;
    if (g <= a1[p + 2])
    p += 2;
    p++;
    z = ((g - a1[p]) - a2[p / 2]) / (g + a1[p]);
    z += z;
    v = z * z;
    r = (((p4 * v + p3) * v + p2) * v + p1) * v * z;
    r += k * r;
    u2 = (r + z * k) + z;
    u1 = 0.0625 * (double)(16 * m - p);
    y1 = 0.0625 * (double)((int)(16.0 * y));
    y2 = y - y1;
    w = u2 * y + u1 * y2;
    w1 = 0.0625 * (double)((int)(16.0 * w));
    w2 = w - w1;
    w = w1 + u1 * y1;
    w1 = 0.0625 * (double)((int)(16.0 * w));
    w2 += (w - w1);
    w = 0.0625 * (double)((int)(16.0 * w2));
    iw1 = 16.0 * (w1 + w);
    w2 -= w;
    while (w2 > 0.0) {
    iw1++;
    w2 -= 0.0625;
    }
    if (iw1 > MAXEXP) {
    cmemsg(FP_POWO, &y);
    return(HUGE);
    }
    if (iw1 < MINEXP) {
    cmemsg(FP_POWU, &y);
    return(0.0);
    }
    m = iw1 / 16;
    if (iw1 >= 0)
    m++;    
    p = 16 * m - iw1;
    z = ((((((q7*w2 + q6)*w2 + q5)*w2 + q4)*w2 + q3)*w2 + q2)*w2 + q1)*w2;
    z = a1[p] + a1[p] * z;
    return(ldexp(z, m));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have all sorts of ints in there. When you do that, the decimal gets truncated. You should make your power functions return floats, and use a float `base`.

Comment: So long as either result or base is float, the result from `/` will be float.